# How can I read the data paste in text area from user and apply the Jquery code on that text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="area" style="width:100%; height:60px;"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>


<script>
$(document).find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function() {
if ($(this).parent().prev().is('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6') != true) {
    $(this).parent().before('<p>xxxxxxx</p>');
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code i want to accept a html file from the user in Text area and then on that text how can i perform above jquery code.

without user interface ,this code is working.
for example

https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/rebpb5h2/5/

here html page is pasted directly without user interface option.

Is it Possible?

can any one help me out,Any Help would be a great help.

Comment: So you needed a way to 'UPLOAD' an html file, read its content and transfer the content to the textarea?

Comment: yup I have attached with this question a fiddle,where the working is perfect but I want it to be converted to User interface GUI Based

Comment: For Refrence below Fiddle is Paste.

http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/12/


Same like this Function, i want to do with this  jquery code.

Comment: I will post a fiddle as an answer, please take a look below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle if it answers your question -- https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/6/

Summary

- The textarea holds the HTML codes to be processed.
- A `<div>` with id `'changedContentWrapper'` holds the result.
- The `<button>` with id `'button'` triggers the processing.

EDIT. I have updated the fiddle, so that you can make changes to the content of the textarea to be processed -- see it here https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/7/

FINAL EDIT. Has two textareas, one for the 'before' processing, and one for the 'after' processing -- https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/9/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's Great Job Done buddy,

But here it is not what i want.

Actually it is not working as i want.

here code is repeated and i dont want any code in html,only Text area code should be there,and all the code should be placed in text area.
once it is paste in Text area,and we click on apply button,then it should perform changes.

Comment: Okay, see the updated fiddle on the EDIT part above.

Comment: for your refrence ,you can see this fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/12/

here i did not use any code in html block, but when you paste any text in text area box,and click on submit button,then it replaces that text by adding "String" keyword(before and after)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show the 'result' ? also inside the textarea or outside of it?

Comment: is it possible to show two windows(Side by side) one for pasting the code(question) and the other for displaying result

Comment: Okay, posting the final outcome, see the FINAL EDIT section above.

Comment: I Am Sorry,its Working great.

Comment: It is working, as long as your input is okay, that is, the header tags H1...H6 should be preceded by another element, or else the result will fail.